# RepositoryNotFoundError : TypeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I am trying to get the following example working:

https://github.com/typeorm/javascript-example/tree/master/src/app3-es6

I am running into the following error:

```
Error
    at new RepositoryNotFoundError (...\node_modules\typeorm\connection\error\RepositoryNotFoundError.js:24:23)
    at Connection.findRepositoryAggregator (...\node_modules\typeorm\connection\Connection.js:513:19)
    at Connection.getRepository (...\node_modules\typeorm\connection\Connection.js:405:21)
    at ...\index.js:27:37
```

```
name: 'RepositoryNotFoundError',
  message: 'No repository for "Post" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?'
```

here is index.js

```
const typeorm = require("typeorm"); // import * as typeorm from "typeorm";
const Post = require("./model/Post"); // import {Post} from "./model/Post";
// import Post from './model/Post.js';
const Category = require("./model/Category"); // import {Category} from "./model/Category";

typeorm.createConnection({
    driver: {
        type: "oracle",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 1521,
        username: "uname",
        password: "pwd",
        sid: "dev"
    },
    entities: [
        __dirname + "/entity/*.js"
    ],
    autoSchemaSync: true
}).then(function (connection) {
    console.log(connection);

    let post = new Post.Post();
    post.title = "Control flow based type analysis";
    post.text = "TypeScript 2.0 implements a control flow-based type analysis for local variables and parameters.";
    post.categories = [new Category.Category(0, "TypeScript"), new Category.Category(0, "Programming")];

    let postRepository = connection.getRepository(Post.Post);
    postRepository.persist(post)
        .then(function(savedPost) {
            console.log("Post has been saved: ", savedPost);
            console.log("Now lets load all posts: ");

            return postRepository.find();
        })
        .then(function(allPosts) {
            console.log("All posts: ", allPosts);
        });
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
});
```

Post.js in /model/

```
/*export */ class Post {
    constructor(id, title, text, categories) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    Post: Post
};
```

Category.js

```
/*export */ class Category {
    constructor(id, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    Category: Category
};
```

PostSchema.js in /entity/

```
const Post = require("../model/Post"); // import {Post} from "../model/Post";
const Category = require("../model/Category"); // import {Category} from "../model/Category";
const PostSchema = {
    target: Post,
    columns: {
        id: {
            primary: true,
            type: "int",
            generated: true
        },
        title: {
            type: "string"
        },
        text: {
            type: "text"
        }
    },
    relations: {
        categories: {
            target: Category,
            type: "many-to-many",
            joinTable: true,
            cascadeInsert: true
        }
    }
};

module.exports = {
    PostSchema: PostSchema
};
```

CategorySchema.js

```
const Category = require("../model/Category"); // import {Category} from "../model/Category";
const CategorySchema = {
    target: Category,
    columns: {
        id: {
            primary: true,
            type: "int",
            generated: true
        },
        name: {
            type: "string"
        }
    }
};

module.exports = {
    CategorySchema: CategorySchema
};
```

i dont know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 22):

It looks like your entity import is not working. If you import via the wildcard:

```
entities: [
    __dirname + "/entity/*.js"
],`
```

Make sure your model is compiled to js. You also could just import

```
createConnection({ 
    ..., 
    entities: [
        Post,
        ...
    ],}).then(...)
```

Comment: I was in a tricky spot where I was running jest tests with supertest, and my express server with typeorm models was failing to make a connection. This solution worked, although I still have no idea what was wrong with my entities path.

Comment: 2 years later, when I am trying to add config options to createConnection it just does not work...

Answer (score 13):

For those who are using typescript and experience this problem: Be reminded that you need to include both `ts` and `js` file suffixes when specifying the entities-path:

- `ts` used when locally running with `ts-node`
- `js` used when having
  built for production via `tsc`.

Code:

```
import * as path from 'path';
// ...
entities: [
    // assuming _dirname is your project root
    path.resolve(__dirname, '**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'),
],
```

Comment: This is a great answer that deserves to be added to the official documentation.

Comment: The answer is correct! I had a similar issue on my NestJs project

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem for months and finally figured out what I was doing wrong.

When you import Entities, make sure the file names are EXACTLY matching. It's not going to throw any errors, but during the run time, it's going to throw the above error.

Ex. In the entity or model classes, if we import like this,

```
import { FooClass } from "./foo-Class.model";
```

it's different from

```
import { FooClass } from "./foo-class.model";
```

It won't show any errors, but when you try to call the table, it will show the exact same error.

Comment: You just saved me after a few hours. Thanks!

Comment: can u plz explain this different. I'm not able to find the difference for your example

Comment: @raghurajendran notice the case difference for the letter "C" in foo-Class and foo-class

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. None of the solutions worked for me. After much debugging I figured out that you'll receive this error if your connection is closed.

So if you are facing this error, make sure your connection is not closed.

```
try {
    connection = getConnection(config.name)
    //after adding this if block, I no longer received this error
    if (!connection.isConnected) { 
        await connection.connect();
    }
} catch(err) {
    connection = await createConnection(config);
}
```

If it is closed, connect it again.

Comment: const connection = getConnection('conn2');const report = await connection.getRepository(Report).findOne({
      rid: rid  });